# Recruitment Advice

Tags: career-development, recruitment, careers

I have just accepted a job but a recruiter is asking me to attend another interview.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on letting them know I'm not interested but not souring the realtionship with the company.

Thanks For The Help.

Comment: @mister positive, I disagree as I am asking about advice on how to respond to the recruiter without ending the realtionship. I do agree that placing in that comment make it seems like a similar question to my previous one. Happy to remove that section to just ask how to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's trying to scare/bully you into the other interview. Don't let him - talented devs can move from public to private sector & back without issue.

You could, of course, attend the other interview simply for practice & to see if the offer is worth considering. If you don't want to do this, simply tell the recruiter "Thank you for your interest, but I've made my choice and am happy to stick with it."

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if anyone had any advice on letting them know I'm not
>   interested

Just say "No thanks. I've already accepted a job and I'm focusing on that."